# How to use/install python 2to3?

Tags: python, python-2to3

From this https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/2to3.html it says that 2to3 should be installed as a script alongside the python interpreter.  However, in my /usr/bin/ folder there are no 2to3 executable, and running `find` from / finds no 2to3 executable either.  I do however have a folder called lib2to3 at /usr/lib64/python{3.4/2.7}/lib2to3 but containing nothing I found relevant.  In python/site-packages/setuptools/ there is a lib2to3_ex.py script, but nothing happens if I run it.  How do I get to the point where I can simply type `2to3 upgradethisscripttopython3.py` ?

Comment: Have you looked in `Tools/scripts`, per the docs? What happens if you just type `2to3` in the command line and hit return?

Comment: `Tools/scripts` often is not in your `PATH`, you might want to add it.

Comment: I don't have the `Tools/scripts` path :S , and as far I have found out, the `Tools/scripts` files are downloaded with the  `python2.7-examples package` in Ubuntu, but so far I haven't found the equivalent package for opensuse (which I'm using)

Answer (score 17):

You need to first install the following packages:

```
apt install 2to3
apt install python3-lib2to3
apt install python3-toolz
```

For windows just install `2to3`

```
pip install 2to3
```

Then, You can simply go to that directory your python file is in and type the following command:

`2to3 ./filename.py`

OR for writing the updated python 3 code to the existing file

`2to3 . -w`

This last will convert all the python files that are in the directory.

Comment: toolz is unrelated to lib2to3

Comment: In Windows, I seemed to only need 2to3, not the other 2 packages.

Answer (score 7):

So the solution is that at least not for me, the Tools/scripts files were not automatically installed. On ubuntu this would be solved by installing `python-examples` which on opensuse is called `python-demo`

Comment: on Fedora/RedHat `yum install python-tools`

Comment: And on newer versions of Ubuntu, `apt-get install 2to3`.

Answer (score 5):

On CentOS (and other RHEL-like distros) you will need to run `yum install python-tools`, which installs `2to3` to `/usr/bin/2to3`

Comment: On RHEL8 / CentOS Stream release 8 install `platform-python-devel`

Answer (score 3):

On Fedora 29, the `python-tools` is not providing `2to3`. I had to install the development package:

```
dnf install python3-devel
```

I found this out by first calling:

```
dnf whatprovides /usr/bin/2to3
```

Answer (score 3):

So far I've been using `pip install 2to3`. Conversions worked like absolute charm!
(I'm on Ubuntu 18.04)

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have the file /usr/bin/2to3-2.7 (or similar).  If one exists, then simply create a symbolic link to it with a link name of 2to3 (e.g.: ln -s 2to3-2.7 /usr/bin/2to3).