# Where can I get the Python 2to3 library on Buildroot

Tags: python, python-2.7, buildroot

I get the following error when importing gmusicapi in Python 2.7 on a Buildroot Linux system:

```
>>> import gmusicapi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "gmusicapi/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from gmusicapi.clients import Webclient, Musicmanager, Mobileclient
  File "gmusicapi/clients/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from gmusicapi.clients.webclient import Webclient
  File "gmusicapi/clients/webclient.py", line 5, in <module>
    from past.builtins import basestring
  File "past/__init__.py", line 88, in <module>
    from past.translation import install_hooks as autotranslate
  File "past/translation/__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from lib2to3.pgen2.parse import ParseError
ImportError: No module named lib2to3.pgen2.parse
```

Python can't find lib2to3. Neither can I ;-). Is there anywhere I can download this library? I'm using Buildroot, so I can't simply do pip installs.

*This is **not** a duplicate of:
[How to use/install python 2to3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31228927/how-to-use-install-python-2to3)*

Comment: According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html), "2to3 will usually be installed with the Python interpreter as a script. It is also located in the `Tools/scripts` directory of the Python root."

Comment: What OS is this? How was Python installed? `lib2to3` is part of the *standard library*, and should have been installed automatically. For example, on Ubuntu, I'd expect the [`libpython2.7-stdlib` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=libpython2.7-stdlib&searchon=names) (which contains `lib2to3`) to have been installed as a dependency of `python2.7`.

Comment: @ForceBru: I don't have this directory, also, I'd expect not a tool but a Python library, because Python code imports it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Linux (Buildroot). Maybe it's in a library which has a misleading name, but there is nothing like lib2to3 or anything that points in that direction.

Comment: @svenema, if your installation has the script, it must also have the library. If it doesn't, make sure you're using the official latest Python 2.7.

Comment: Then this looks relevant: https://github.com/buildroot/buildroot/blob/master/package/python/0018-Add-an-option-to-disable-lib2to3.patch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lib2to3` is a *standard library*, normally included with Python. However, the buildroot build system [explicitly removes it](https://github.com/buildroot/buildroot/blob/master/package/python/0018-Add-an-option-to-disable-lib2to3.patch).

I'm not certain if Buildroot actually lets you disable their patch; the [`python.mk` file](https://github.com/buildroot/buildroot/blob/2cd4c845865ca86ee3d7b015670063b347cb49f8/package/python/python.mk#L157-L169) appears to hardcode the flag:

```
PYTHON_CONF_OPTS += \
    --without-cxx-main \
    --without-doc-strings \
    --with-system-ffi \
    --disable-pydoc \
    --disable-test-modules \
    --disable-lib2to3 \
    --disable-gdbm \
    --disable-tk \
    --disable-nis \
    --disable-dbm \
    --disable-pyo-build \
    --disable-pyc-build
```

and I don't see an option to add `--enable-lib2to3` to override that. You may want to check with the Buildroot community if this is at all an option. Otherwise, I'd just edit that make file.

Comment: It's not ideal to use 2to3 on embedded systems, that's why  it turned out it was disabled.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue by running below command on my Ubuntu 20.04 machine:
`sudo apt-get install -y python3.7-lib2to3`

Comment: The question is specifically about how to install it on a Buildroot system.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: patching the past library (source of the problem):

```
--- past/translation/__init__.py.orig   2017-09-24 08:23:47.646644743 +0200
+++ past/translation/__init__.py    2018-01-01 10:31:36.584576652 +0100
@@ -38,8 +38,32 @@
 import os
 import sys
 import copy
-from lib2to3.pgen2.parse import ParseError
-from lib2to3.refactor import RefactoringTool
+
+try:
+    from lib2to3.pgen2.parse import ParseError
+
+except ImportError:
+
+    class ParseError(SyntaxError):
+        pass
+
+try:
+    from lib2to3.refactor import RefactoringTool
+
+except ImportError:
+
+    class RefactoringTool:
+
+        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
+            self._args = [repr(a) for a in args]
+            self._args += ["{}={!r}".format(k, v) for k, v in kwargs.items()]
+
+        def __repr__(self):
+            return "{}({})".format(self.__class__.__name__, ", ".join(self._args))
+
+        def refactor_string(self, *args, **kwargs):
+            raise NotImplementedError("dummy RefactoringTool")
+

 from libfuturize import fixes
```

found here: https://github.com/PythonCharmers/python-future/issues/209

If someone can point me to a downloadable lib2to3 I'll accept that answer, for now this workaround will do the trick.

Comment: Please post your question to Buildroot's mailing list.